# How to modify a Dockerfile with an existing ENTRYPOINT to add "wait-for-it.sh"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to modify the Docker image `wrouesnel/postgres_exporter` such that it can be used in a Docker Compose multi-container application and waits for Postgres to accept connections. My project has the following structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── exporter
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── wait-for-it.sh
```

where `docker-compose.yml` reads

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  exporter:
    build: exporter
    environment:
      DATA_SOURCE_NAME: "postgresql://postgres:mypassword@db:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
    ports:
      - "9187:9187"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

and `wait-for-it.sh` is obtained from https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh, and the `Dockerfile` reads

```
FROM wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
COPY wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "./postgres_exporter"]
```

However, if I `docker-compose build` and attempt to `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
> docker-compose up
Recreating postgres-performance-testing_exporter_1 ... 
Recreating postgres-performance-testing_exporter_1 ... done
Attaching to postgres-performance-testing_db_1, postgres-performance-testing_exporter_1
exporter_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I don't understand which file it is not finding and why not? Aren't both copied to my `WORKDIR`?

Comment: You can start the exporter container manually from shell using "docker run -it exporter /bin/bash" and then try running the entrypoint commands manually to find which command is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run the bash script in `wrouesnel/postgres_exporter` image as [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) as wait-for-it is totaly based on bash.

if you look into Dockerfile of [wrouesnel](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter/blob/master/Dockerfile)  is from scratch and there is nothing in this image at all.

```
FROM scratch
ARG binary
COPY $binary /postgres_exporter
EXPOSE 9187
ENTRYPOINT [ "/postgres_exporter" ]
```

So the hack around with such an image is to use them as multi-stage image and copy the binaries and extend your image.

```
FROM wrouesnel/postgres_exporter 

FROM debian:7.11-slim
RUN useradd -u 20001 postgres_exporter
USER postgres_exporter
COPY --from=0 /postgres_exporter /postgres_exporter
EXPOSE 9187
COPY wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh
USER root
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
USER postgres_exporter
RUN pwd
ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "./postgres_exporter"]
```